# How to generate list of hex numbers?

Tags: org-mode, linux, column

I am using emacs with org mode.

**Question 1:**

I want to number a column in a table in hex.
E.g.

```
| 0x00 | xyz | .. |
| 0x01 | abc | .. |
```

I want to auto generate first column.
Any ideas how to do this in org mode?

**Question 2:**

How to generate a list of numbers/alphabets etc. (in hex, decimal) in emacs (need not be org mode)?

**PS**: Please let me know if there are any linux/bash tricks to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is a method using an elisp formula:

```
| hex  | comment |
|------+---------|
| 0x00 |         |
| 0x01 |         |
| 0x02 |         |
| 0x03 |         |
| 0x04 |         |
| 0x05 |         |
| 0x06 |         |
| 0x07 |         |
| 0x08 |         |
| 0x09 |         |
| 0x0A |         |
| 0x0B |         |
| 0x0C |         |
#+TBLFM: $1='(format "0x%02X" (- @# 2))
```

[`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html) takes a format string much like printf in C.

Then `@#` gives the current row number, to which I subtract 2 so row 2 displays 0.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer to question 2 -- how generate a list of hex numbers -- based on keyboard macros and calc.

## Prepare Calc

Set calc to display in radix 16.

```
C-x * c d r 16 RET
```

Optional: Hide the calc buffers by pressing q.

## Record a suitable Macro

E.g. do this

```
f3 f3 M-b C-x * w C-x * w C-e RET f4
```

## Use the Macro

```
f4 f4 ...
```

Or do e.g.

```
C-u 256 f4
```

## Beautification Hint

Search and replace may be used to change the format of the list.

Comment: `C-x * c d r 16 q` should be `C-x * c d r 16 <RET>` ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks.  I improved the answer, hopefully.